# Javascript Q Promise Sequence Order with Arguments

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, q

I'm using Q sequences (Nodejs) as described [here](https://github.com/kriskowal/q#sequences)

I need to return these async calls in order even though they take different amounts of time. How can I do this?

I tried:

```js
function sampleAsyncCall(wait,order) {
    var deferred = Q.defer();

    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log(order)
        deferred.resolve();
    }, wait);

    return deferred.promise;
}

sampleAsyncCall(400,"first")
    .then(sampleAsyncCall(300,"second"))
    .then(sampleAsyncCall(200,"third"))
    .then(sampleAsyncCall(100,"forth"));

Returns:
forth
third
second 
first
```

What's confusing is that if I rewrite it to not use arguments it returns in the order I want.

```js
function first() {
    var deferred = Q.defer();

    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log("first")
        deferred.resolve();
    }, 400);

    return deferred.promise;
}

function second() {
    var deferred = Q.defer();

    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log("second")
        deferred.resolve();
    }, 300);

    return deferred.promise;
}

function third() {
    var deferred = Q.defer();

    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log("third")
        deferred.resolve();
    }, 200);

    return deferred.promise;
}

function forth() {
    var deferred = Q.defer();

    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log("forth")
        deferred.resolve();
    }, 100);

    return deferred.promise;
}

first().then(second).then(third).then(forth);

Returns:
first
second
third
forth
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
sampleAsyncCall(400,"first")
    .then(sampleAsyncCall(300,"second"))
    .then(sampleAsyncCall(200,"third"))
    .then(sampleAsyncCall(100,"forth"));
```

The `.then()` function should receive as parameter a *function* and **not** a *promise* (that your function call resolves to).

**EDIT:**

Try something like this:

```
sampleAsyncCall(400,"first")
    .then(function(){
        return sampleAsyncCall(300,"second")
    })
    .then(function(){
        return sampleAsyncCall(200,"third")
    })
    .then(function(){
        return sampleAsyncCall(100,"forth")
    });
```

Comment: Makes sense but that still gives the wrong order (first, forth, third, second). Any thoughts?

Comment: @Charlie, just added some `console.log` calls in my example and some explanation. Please review

Comment: You need to return promises from asynchronous functions - that includes callbacks that you pass to `then`. I hope you don't mind my blunt edit, feel free to rollback it

Comment: Also do you know why you need the function(){return...}? Isn't sampleAsyncCall already a "promise returning function?"